# AWS S3 Rest API with Android Retrofit V2 library, uploaded image is damaged

Tags: android, rest, amazon-s3, retrofit

I'm trying upload a `Image` from my **Android APP to Amazon AWS S3** and I need use **AWS Restful API**.

I'm using [Retrofit 2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to make to the request.

My application is connecting successfully with *Amazon S3* and performing the request as expected, but when I try to view the `Image` from the **Bucket**, the picture does not open. I downloaded the `Image` to my pc and tried to open but keep getting the message that the image is corrupted.

Lets see my complete code bellow.

**My Gradle dependencies**

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.2'
```

**Here is created a File and starts the request**

```
File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);
uploadImage(body, "photo_name.jpeg");
```

**Retrofit Interface**

```
public interface AwsS3 {

    @Multipart
    @PUT("/{Key}")
    Call<String> upload(@Path("Key") String Key,
                @Header("Content-Length") long length,
                @Header("Accept") String accept,
                @Header("Host") String host,
                @Header("Date") String date,
                @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
                @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                @Part("Body") RequestBody body);
}
```

**Utils class to the mount the credentials**

```
public class AWSOauth {

    public static String getOAuthAWS(Context context, String fileName)  throws Exception{

        String secret = context.getResources().getString(R.string.s3_secret);
        String access = context.getResources().getString(R.string.s3_access_key);
        String bucket = context.getResources().getString(R.string.s3_bucket);

        return gerateOAuthAWS(secret, access, bucket,fileName);
    }

    private static String gerateOAuthAWS(String secretKey, String accessKey, String bucket, String imageName) throws Exception {

        String contentType = "image/jpeg";

        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE', 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' 'Z").withLocale(Locale.US);
        String ZONE = "GMT";
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        DateTime dtLondon = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(ZONE)).plusHours(1);
        String formattedDate = dtLondon.toString(fmt);

        String resource = "/" + bucket + "/" + imageName;

        String stringToSign = "PUT" + "\n\n" + contentType + "\n" + formattedDate + "\n" + resource;

        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1"));

        String signature = ( Base64.encodeToString(hmac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.DEFAULT)).replaceAll("\n", "");

        String oauthAWS = "AWS " + accessKey + ":" + signature;

        return  oauthAWS;
    }
}
```

**Lastly the method to make a request**

```
 public void uploadImage(RequestBody body, String fileName){

        String bucket = getString(R.string.s3_bucket);

        Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://" + bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        AwsS3 service = restAdapter.create(AwsS3.class);

        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE', 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' 'Z").withLocale(Locale.US);
        String ZONE = "GMT";
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        DateTime dtLondon = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(ZONE)).plusHours(1);
        String formattedDate = dtLondon.toString(fmt);

        try {

            String oauth = AWSOauth.getOAuthAWS(getApplicationContext(), fileName);

            Call<String> call = service.upload(fileName, body.contentLength(), "/**", bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com", formattedDate,  body.contentType().toString(), oauth, body);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<String> response) {
                    Log.d("tag", "response : " + response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("tag", "response : " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I appreciate any helps, thanks in advance!

Comment: No exception is thrown? What is the status code of the request?

Comment: No exception, the image is uploaded and response is 200 OK.

Comment: When you say the image was uploaded successfully, did you also compare the md5sum? After uploading successfully, try comparing the md5sum of the object you uploaded. This way you can be damn sure that the object was not changed at all. Also you say `when I try open the image but it is damaged`.. are you trying to view it on desktop?

Comment: I try to open the browser and on the desktop too!

Comment: @A.Anderson Do you have a sample (any public link?) of the image/object you are trying to upload?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri, can be any image, I'm getting the image from my gallery in my app, and the image is ok before upload

Comment: Did you solve this issue finally? If so, can you post the working code.

Comment: @AritraRoy, I resolved not the problem, I'm using Retrofit 1.

Comment: got any workaround with retrofit2 ?

Comment: I don't know if this still working in 2020, even there is no region in url
`.baseUrl("http://" + bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RequestBody avatarBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image"),file);
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), avatarBody);


@Multipart
@POST(url)
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImageAmazon(
            @Part MultipartBody.Part filePart);
```

I had same experience, and solved it by https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2424 this solution

Answer (score 10):

I have used Retrofit 2 resolve
and I use `Body` instead of `Part` for your `RequestBody` in interface

```
@PUT("")
Call<String> nameAPI(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody body);
```

and java code

```
// Prepare image file
File file = new File(pathImg);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);

Call<String> call = SingletonApiServiceS3.getInstance().getService().nameAPI(
        path,
       requestBody
);
call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, final Response<String> response) {

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Your handling
        } else {
            // Your handling
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onFailure : "+t.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

Comment: I needed this for s3 PUT call, Thanks a lot

Comment: this helped thanks. I removed @Multipart and just added Body

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem,  and as I use Fiddler checked the HTTP request  content, I found retrofit 2.0.0 beta1 has a different with 1.9.0.

In my problem, the different of HTTP request content prevent server get the correct data.

In order to make a same HTTP request content, i do next steps using retrofit 2.0.0 deta1.

---

**In the retrofit service, add a form-data header for the http request;**

```
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=95416089-b2fd-4eab-9a14-166bb9c5788b")
```

`int retrofit 2.0.0 deta1`, the header using `@Multipart` will get a data like this:

> Content-Type: multipart/mixed

as the deafult value is mixed, and has no boundary title.

---

**Do not using `@Multipart` to upload file, just using `@Body` `RequestBody`**

if you using `@Multipart` to request Server, you have to pass param(file) through

`@Part(key)`, then a new problem you will get.  May be retrofit 2.0.0beta1 has a BUG ..., `@Multipart` generate a bad http request compile with 1.9.0.

---

**When you call the method, you need pass MultipartRequestBody to @Body RequestBody**

Using `MultipartBuilder` to create a `MultipartRequestBody`, when you new `MultipartBuilder`, call this consturt:

```
new MultipartBuilder("95416089-b2fd-4eab-9a14-166bb9c5788b")
```

the param is you set `int @headers(boundary=)`

```
builder.addFormDataPart(String name, String filename, RequestBody value)
```

This method will help form a data like below int HTTP request content:

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imgFile";
>   filename="IMG_20150911_113029.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpg
>   Content-Length: 1179469

`RequestBody` value is what you has generate in your code.

I just resolve this problem temporary.

Hope can help you!

Comment: their approach seems ok, I figured out that the s3 AWS need that content is to be sent in the request body and not as multipart.

Comment: I have a trouble about Content-Length of a part, Retrofit auto add Content-Length for the RequestBody and also each part, and server does not allowed this (I tested the API via Postman and it works well), 
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2604
Do you have any ideas? or I have to throw out Retrofit?

Answer (score 3):

You are sending a multipart payload, but forcing the Content-type to be `image/jpeg`.  Your jpg is corrupt because S3 probably saved the multipart headers into your jpg file since you told it the whole message was a JPG.  Since you do not actually have multiple parts to send, you can drop the `Multipart` annotation and use `Body` instead of `Part` for your `RequestBody`

```
public interface AwsS3 {

    @PUT("/{Key}")
    Call<String> upload(@Path("Key") String Key,
                @Header("Content-Length") long length,
                @Header("Accept") String accept,
                @Header("Host") String host,
                @Header("Date") String date,
                @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
                @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                @Body RequestBody body);
}
```

You should also be able to remove explicitly setting the `Content-type` and `Content-length` headers.

Comment: It make sense, I'll trying this approach later!

Comment: So I tried, but does not work well. The image is not sent right!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Retrofit 2, just Retrofit 1, so YMMV, but I believe that the typical way to do what you're trying to do is to use TypedFile where you are attempting to use RequestBody.

I'm guessing that Retrofit uses RequestBody internally.

You would create the TypedFile something like:

```
TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", new File("path/to/your/file"));
```

and your interface would be:

```
   @Multipart
    @PUT("/{Key}")
    Call<String> upload(@Path("Key") String Key,
                @Header("Content-Length") long length,
                @Header("Accept") String accept,
                @Header("Host") String host,
                @Header("Date") String date,
                @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
                @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                @Part("Body") TypedFile body);
}
```

There's a decent example at 
https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-how-to-upload-files/

Comment: Thanks for answer, I believe that be some wrong with my request body, because the request is performed ok, but I'm using Retrofit 2, TypedFile was removed from lib, and I cant make downgrade, I need use the version 2.

Comment: Have you considered leaving off the explicit Content-Type and Content-Length headers, and letting Retrofit obtain them from the RequestBody ?

Comment: This does not work AWS api rest requires that this header is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use retrofit 2 to upload the image/file

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/attachment")
Call<JsonPrimitive> addAttachment(@Part MultipartBody.Part imageFile);
```

Now to make the call:

```
 RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part imageFileBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
```

Note : Make sure you are using retrofit2 as for some reason I was unable to upload image using retrofit1 library.